# Why is WCF replacing my endpoint name?

Tags: .net, wcf, service, wcf-configuration

I've got a service with the following endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          name="SomeServiceDotNetEndpoint" contract="Contracts.ISomeService" />
```

When I add this service reference to another project, the app config file shows the following client endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="http://test.example.com/Services/SomeService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService"
                contract="SomeService.ISomeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService" />
```

Now, an endpoint with the name `BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService` is never defined in the service's web config file. When I try to create a new channel factory with the following code:

```
var someServiceChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>("SomeServiceDotNetEndPoint", endpoint);
```

It fails, telling me that there isn't matching contract/endpoint at that address. I've also tried using `"BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService"` and I get the same error.

```
Could not find endpoint element with name 'SomeServiceDotNetEndPoint' and
contract 'SomeService.ISomeService' in the ServiceModel client configuration
section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your
application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found
in the client element.
```

So, where did `BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService` come from, why was my original endpoint name overridden, and how can I get the service to recognize the endpoints I'm trying to hit?

Answer (score 2):

When you define an endpoint on the service side you don't need specify a name. But on the client side you should provide unique name in case that you want to use channelFactory to create a proxy.

In summary:

Service web.config

```
<endpoint address="" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="Contracts.ISomeService" />
```

Client app.config

```
<endpoint address="http://test.com/SomeService"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          name="someServiceEndpoint"
          contract="Contracts.ISomeService" />
```

code

```
var someServiceChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<ISomeService>("someServiceEndpoint", endpoint);
```

Hope this helps,

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

The point of confusion here is that most "name" values in a WCF service configuration are implementation details that are not published outside of the service. Endpoint names, binding names, service behavior names are only visible to the service and to clients.

When you created the service reference the client generated an endpoint name based on the service information that is published: addresss, binding, and contract... and came up with the name "BasicHttpBinding_ISomeService". You will find that all service references to a service that exposes ISomeService using BasicHttpBinding gets the same name.

**So your endpoint name wasn't overridden. The client simply never knew what it was.**

The easiest way to call the service is using the service reference generated client. If you used the default `ServiceReferece1` namespace that that wizard choose:

```
ServiceReference1.SomeServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.SomeServiceClient("endpointname");
```

Comment: Ernie, I was able to get the expected results, but only after deleting the `<service>` node in question and recreating using the WCF configuration editor. I still haven't been able to determine what was happening with that node that would cause it to be unrecognizable to the client, since every other service behaved correctly. Anywho, thanks for your input.